# Other than a "Lullaby" how does Hulk turn back into Bruce Banner?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Age of Ultron*, after Scarlet Witch makes Banner hulk out without him willing it; you do see Banner again but you can tell he is still affected by Scarlet Witch's mind manipulation

Which raises the question, as we don't see if Nat was able to get Banner's attention long enough to do a lullaby, what has to happen for the Hulk to become Banner again?

Is it a question of energy as in once the Hulk is out of energy he reverts back to Banner or is it a psychological/health thing (like for him to hulk out he let's his heart rate climb)

Comment: Get his heart rate below 200 or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, Hulk reverts to Banner when he calms down.  The change to the Hulk is triggered primarily by the rising adrenaline levels caused by anger or other extreme emotions.  When they drop, he can return to Puny Banner Form.

(I say "Can" cause there are examples of the Hulk being knocked unconscious and restrained in the comics, but staying as the Hulk, so the rules are loose as the narrative requires)

So in the first Avengers film, the fall from the Helicarrier was enough to knock the Hulk out, and awoke as Banner. Natasha's lullaby (likely part of an implanted trigger) calmed him down as well.

Comment: What about in Age of Ultron, Scarlet Witch would definitely be causing his emotions to run amock; that's what she does, did Tony manage to knock The Hulk out with that last punch?